# xarray annual grouping across years

Tags: python-xarray

I am computing annual means of my data with:

```
sst_ANN = ds['sst'].groupby(ds['time.year']).mean(dim='time')
```

which is surely elegant. Now I want to do the same thing, except compute the annual mean running from June to May in the year after, instead of calendar year. Would there be a similar one-liner to do this?

Comment: This is how it can be done in Pandas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341272/using-groupby-on-pandas-dataframe-to-group-by-financial-year

Comment: This is how far I got: 
`my_time = pd.to_datetime(ds_sst['time'].values)`
`ds_sst.groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex( ds_sst['time'].values ).shift(-5,freq='m').year)`

Gives : `TypeError: 'group' must be an xarray.DataArray or the name of an xarray variable or dimension`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should be using xarray's resample method instead of groupby (they are similar in this case but resample is slightly easier to manipulate to do what you want).

For xarray 0.10.0 and later, this would look like:

```
sst_ANN = ds['sst'].resample(time='AS-JUN').mean('time')
```

For older versions of xarray, it would look like:

```
sst_ANN = ds['sst'].resample(freq='AS-JUN', dim='time', how='mean')
```

In both cases, we use an ["anchored offset"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21//timeseries.html#anchored-offsets). The `AS-JUN` translates to "annual, start of period, beginning in June".